# I want create calender From todays date to onward, and all friday disable, also want disable some specific dates in Android

Tags: java, android, jquery, datetime, datepicker

I want to create own calender From today's date to onward(Disable Backward month,year,dates), and disable all Monday and Friday,also want disable some specific dates in android. If any solution for that suggest me,

Comment: use this library it has all you want https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

Answer (score 0):

1.Use this [caldroid lib](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid)

2.Get date  that you want to disable 
Like you want friday

```
    String start = "22/12/2015";
    String end = "12/12/2016";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Calendar scal=Calendar.getInstance();
    try {
        scal.setTime(dateFormat.parse(start));
        Calendar ecal=Calendar.getInstance();
        ecal.setTime(dateFormat.parse(end));

        ArrayList<Date> fridayDates=new ArrayList<>();

        while(!scal.equals(ecal)){
            scal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            if(scal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)==Calendar.FRIDAY){
                fridayDates.add(scal.getTime());
                System.out.println(scal.getTime());
            }
        }

    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

3.You will get fridayDates array that have to pass in

```
caldroid.setDisableDates(fridayDates);
```

Comment: Hi parag, Thanks I  use  caldroid lib and its sample activity i successfully hide before todays date,month year. but all these things happen when i click on customize button,  here I want without click on Customize button open calender with all above scenario and i am not able to find from this library where to set my calender.

Comment: Simple @SunilZ download https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid and run it ,it have already working demo just u have to setDisableDates as per your logic

Comment: No Parag,
   i use Caldroid library and i am success with hide dates before today and manage desable perticular dates. When i run demo there is one calender and 2 buttons which is customize and show dialog. On click of CUSTOMIZE Button all above scenario is run but i want when run demo Direct Customized Calendar open no need to click Customized Button and i am not able to do this.